# compare sql insert date and c# date time

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a transaction website. When a subscription is created the modified date is inserted in the table. What I am trying to accomplish is to uniquely identify that record. Here is that I am trying:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
Debug.WriteLine("Current Timestamp is: " + currentTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"));

sCmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct userID FROM table WHERE Report_OID = @reportID AND ModifiedDate = @currentTime";
sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportID", reportID);
sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentTime", currentTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"));

Output: 

Current Timestamp is: 2016-06-09 10:19:16:586
Modified Date is: 2016-06-09 10:19:16.553
```

Tried this:

```
sCmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
IDataReader reader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader != null &&  reader.Read())
{
    long lastInsertedID = reader.GetInt64(0);
    Debug.WriteLine("return id is : " + lastInsertedID);
}

Got this error:
'LAST_INSERT_ID' is not a recognized built-in function name.

This error may have happened due to the createSubscription method call to create a subscription in the reporting service webservice which handles the insert in the database. I do not have insert statements in my code.
```

This will fail as the milliseconds wont be the same. The reason I want to use milliseconds is to prevent multiple userids if two users insert a subscription around the same time.

What I am trying to figure out is compare these two dates so I can accurately get the userID of my transaction and not worry about grabbing someone else user id if two transactions are inserted at the same time. Is this possible? Am I trying to solve this the wrong way. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How does your code know if you have the right UserID?  Are you inserting a record and then trying to query it back out immediately?  Relying on a timestamp alone as an identifier is unusual, because while it is HIGHLY improbable that you will have a conflict, it is not impossible,

Comment: There is some issues with it right now as the userID is supposed to be the session id of the user when they log in. While calling the createSubscription method it creates a ownerID and not the userid  of the report. There is some conflicts in trying to assign the ownerID as the userID. What I am trying to look into is checking the ownerID, the selected report and time stamp which should give me the right ownerID of the report.

Comment: And yes, I am trying to query out the id immediately.

Comment: So confusing.  If userID is supposed to be session id then fix it.  No kidding milliseconds are going to  change from on call of DateTime.Now to the next.  Why not just save modified date of the insert (even though it is not guaranteed to be unique)?   Better just save the usrID of the insert (even if it is wrong).  Even if LAST_INSERT_ID() was a real function it would not fix your problem.

Comment: @Paparazzi While I try to do it the way you suggested, I have foreign key constraint issues. I am new to C# and this is my first project so its been very confusing trying to figure out the ssrs service, db, and the c# code. I will research into the foreign key issues further.

Comment: You have problem statement issue.  You don't even show the insert.  This is an XY where you ask for a fixed to an invalid perceived solution.

Comment: @Paparazzi Like I said before in my question, there is no insert statement. What I am doing is calling a sql reporting service method which handles the creation of the subscription and inserting it in the db part. Here is more information on createSubscription method if you are interested. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258083(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry, can't help you.   Really with all those inputs you cannot find the one inserted.

Comment: @Paparazzi No problem. I will use one of these inputs to get the one inserted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paparazzi, I created another select statement to get the lastest subscription by using the email address and creating a datetime variable before the createSubscription method is called I was able to get the most recent insert id and its working now.

```
DateTime subscriptionCreateTime = DateTime.Now;
CreateSubscription(); //Create a new ssrs subscription

//SQL connection here
sCmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct ownerID FROM db.table WHERE Report_ID = @reportID AND ModifiedDate >= @currentTimeStamp AND Description like @emailAddress";
sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportID", gRptID);
sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", "%"+tbTO.Text+"%");
sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentTimeStamp", subscriptionCreatedTime);
SqlDataReader reader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for the pseudo-code (I don't use MySQL often), but the proper way to do this is to modify your insert to return the identity of the last record inserted by your statement instead of trying to match things up using timestamps and userIds.  The code will be simpler and more reliable.  This is done in MySQL using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function (the approximation of MS SQL's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function).

For example, your insert (assuming the table has an indentity column called "FooID" might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES ('Biz');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If the new record had a FooID of 148, then your statement would insert the record and return 148, at which point you could:

```
SELECT Bar FROM Foo WHERE FooID = 148;
```

That should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: [Error] Additional information: 'LAST_INSERT_ID' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I do not actually have a insert statement, I am calling a createSubscription method that handles the insert in the reporting database. Which is why I am having issues and have to query for the recently inserted data. I have added more information in my code above. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of the inputs to find the record.  You have several.